# apache-airflow systemd file using a conda env

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, airflow

I'm trying to run `apache-airflow` on a Ubuntu 16.04 file, using systemd. I roughly followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/hgrif/airflow-tutorial) and installed/setup the following:

- Miniconda 2, 64-bit
- Installed gcc (`sudo apt-get install gcc`)
- Conda environment, using the `yml` file of the tutorial

Within the following conda environment:

- export AIRFLOW_HOME="/home/ubuntu/airflow"

When I test Airflow, everything works fine:

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

But whenever I try to launch airflow using a systemd file, it fails. The systemd file makes use of the conda environment, as far as I understand correctly. My systemd file looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/airflow-tutorial/bin/airflow webserver --port 8080
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start/enable the systemd daemon, status returns the following error:

```
airflow-webserver.service - Airflow webserver daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-09-13 08:59:00 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 18410 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/airflow-tutorial/bin/airflow webserver --port 8080 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18410 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 13 08:59:00 ip-172-31-46-255 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 13 08:59:00 ip-172-31-46-255 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 13 08:59:00 ip-172-31-46-255 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The following is `airflow-webserver.service` that works for me with a virtual environment:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/airflow/webserver.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'source /usr/local/airflow/venv/bin/activate ; airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How does this translate to my situation, with ubuntu user and conda environment? I can't get it working for some reason, struggling for days. I changed execStart in my case to: `/bin/bash -c "source activate airflow-tutorial ; airflow webserver --port 8080"`, but no success.

Comment: Did you reload using `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart airflow-webserver`?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `journalctl -u airflow-webserver.service -b`?

Answer (score 0):

One completetely different, but much easier solution which worked for me:

1. Add new sudo user with sudo rights, for example `airflow`
2. Install `apache-airflow` in environment as `airflow` user
3. Run airflow daemon using: `airflow webserver --port 8080 -D`

This runs airflow as daemon background process. You can just switch back to other user and continue creating dags, etc.

Comment: Here if you make updates on airflow in your `conda` environment, they will not translate here and you will need to manually make the same updates here. I don't think that this re-syncing of environments between users is a good idea for long term airflow support.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @kaxil kinda worked for me! But with slight modifications.

I have my Airflow installed(Using Anaconda)and is at the location:

```
#-> whereis airflow
airflow: /root/anaconda3/bin/airflow
```

Adding the below line in `airflow-webserver.service` file solved the issue for me.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'source /root/anaconda3/bin/activate ; airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid'
```

I got another error after it saying, `Error: /run/airflow doesn't exist. Can't create pidfile.` ,
Adding the below under `[Service]` solved that issue as well

```
RuntimeDirectory=airflow
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0775
```